# The forgetful functor from Groups to Semigroups

Tags: ct.category-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

While teaching this term I found myself reminded of the fact that the "usual" definition of a group homomorphism is really the definition of a semigroup homomorphism, applied to semigroups that happen to be groups. By this I mean that if $G$ and $H$ are groups and $\phi:G \to H$ is a semigroup homomorphism, then one can deduce that $\phi(e_G)=e_H$ and $\phi(x^{-1})=\phi(x)^{-1}$ for all $x\in G$. So in particular, groups that happen to be isomorphic as semigroups are isomorphic as groups (this is actually the consequence I needed, for my own peace of mind).

(Remark: this is in contrast with what happens with rings-without-identity and their homomorphisms, compared with unital rings and unital ring homomorphisms.)

On a related note: I have a vague memory of seeing something which was either on the n-category café blog, or something that John Baez linked to elsewhere, which led the reader through the proof that if $S$ is a semigroup for which each left translation $L_a: x\mapsto ax$ and each right translation $R_a: x\mapsto xa$ are bijective, then $S$ is actually a group. Once again this indicates that groups are not semigroups with extra data but semigroups whose binary operation has particular properties.

**Question 1.** My category theory being quite rusty these days: is all of this encompassed by some kind of monadic adjunction machinery? and is this also to do with the "stuff" versus "structure" distinction/dichotomy?

**Question 2.** Has any expository/pedagogical text actually attempted to take this point of view? I don't mean mentioning monadic adjunctions before defining groups, but rather the more modest approach of discussing semigroups and semigroup homomorphisms before introducing the basic properties of groups.

I suspect that words like "Maltsev category" (or "Malcev category") may feature in the full general picture, but if possible I'd welcome references or explanations that are pitched a bit closer to the ground.

P.S. if this is not seeming "research-level" then feel free to imagine the analogous questions for semigroup objects in other monoidal categories like ${\sf Ban}_1$ or dualizing to coalgebra settings. I actually have LCQG vaguely in mind...

Comment: Small note, analogous to the group case, for some more examples: a homomorphism of semigroups between two inverse semigroups is also a homomorphism of inverse semigroups.

Comment: A few things can be said about this at the category theoretic level, but nothing very deep come to my mind: Categorically speaking, this justs means that Groups are a full subcategory of semigroups. It can be phrased as "Being a group is a property of a semigroups" (and not a structure on a semigroup). This characterization in terms of left and right action being invertible is a way to phrase the definition directly as a property to make it more apparent. In terms of monads properties it also translate as the fact that the "Free group on a semi-group" monad is an idempotent monad.

Comment: With respect to question 1 : yes, that's *exactly* what the property vs structure distinction is meant to encompass. Something is a property if : 1- asking whether an object has it is a question with a yes/no answer and 2- morphisms between objects that have it are the same as "morphisms of objects that have it". If you only have 1-, then this is what's called a property-like structure (e.g. "unital" is a property-like structure of a nonunital ring)

Comment: Oftentimes you ask about property vs structure in the case of an adjunction (say monadic to ensure that at least it's actually about forgetting structure); and then as Simon says, it being a "property" will mean that the counit is an equivalence, equivalently that the associated monad is idempotent (I'm seeing the right adjoint as the forgetful one; dualize everything otherwise)

Comment: You just need both left and right translations by every element to be surjective to axiomatize groups.  Injective is for free

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Thanks! I took embarrassingly long to figure out the solution to this "exercise" (eventually a walk and some fresh air did the trick) -- is this somehow a folklore result, or an exercise in Howie's book(s) that I've overlooked?

Comment: @YemonChoi, I’m pretty sure you can find it in Clifford and Preston.  Maybe they say group =left and right simple.  Ive given it as an exercise in Algebra class with varying degrees of success.

Comment: Because a monic epimorphism is not necessarily an isomorphism in an arbitrary category, we can have internal monoids with cancellation in a category that are not necessarily internal groups. An example for the category of topological spaces is given by the group of homeomorphisms of the Cantor space minus a point, equipped with the compact-open topology. The group multiplication is continuous, but the operation of taking the inverse is not. See this article by Jan Dijkstra: https://www.cs.vu.nl/~dijkstra/research/papers/2005compactopen.pdf